# Import Python file within a different parent directory

Tags: python, import, directory, parent, subdirectory

I have the following directory structure:

```
- src
    - __init__.py
    - scripts
        - __init__.py
        - preprocessing.py
    - project1
        - main.py
    - project2
        - main.py
```

I'm trying to access the script(s) inside the `scripts` folder from within both the `main.py` files.

I've tried adding in the `__init__.py` (blank) files, and importing with `import scripts`, `from src import scripts`, and `from .. import scripts`. None of these seem to work.

I either get: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`, or no module found.

Thanks in advance!

---

P.S. I assume that the directory structure will get deeper soon (e.g. multiple subdirectories within `scripts` and `project1` / `project2`). So if these is an easy way to deal with this as well, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Is the directory that contains `src` in your `sys.path`?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.10. I tried adding it to my `sys.path` but not change really. Also, I've heard that using the `__init__.py` means you don't have to change your `sys.path` as it can be imported as a package.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with that (albeit not the cleanest one) is to manually add the root directory to the sys.path variable so that python can look for modules in it, for example, in your main.py you may add these lines at the top:

```
#/src/project1/main.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '\\..\\')  # this is the src directory
```

This will allow python to look for modules in the directory above the one running the script, and this will work:

```
import scripts.preprocessing
```

Keep in mind that python will only look for modules in the same directory or below as the script is running. If you start /src/project2/main.py, python doesn't know anything about /src/project1/ or /src/scripts/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to avoid adding this to every file that wants access to the `scripts`

Comment: You can also add the lines to the __init__.py of a directory, all the python files in that directory should then have access to the scripts.

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of these lines in the `init.py` please?